# Effect of Trig Functions on Frame Rate in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm working on a ping-pong simulation program in which I have to calculate deflection angles based upon the angle of the paddle and incoming ball trajectory. I've developed a system of equations that calculates deflection. Unfortunately, it involves a system of at least thirty trig functions that can't really be simplified and must be run once during each draw function.
My question is: How much will this slow my program? 
Without the functions implemented the program runs fine on  my new iMac, but on any older computer it already has a great deal of lag as a result of OPENGL and probably some inefficiency on my part.
Will running that many trig functions substantially affect my framerate? If so, would replacing the trig functions with taylor polynomials and then simplifying be, in theory, any better?

Comment: How have you ended up needing 30 trig functions?

Comment: The only way I could manage to solve the ball deflection in 3D was with a graphical representation. As a result, I basically had to convert a graphic solution to a numerical solution. Doing so involved a lot of trig functions. Project documentation can be found at pongassist.blogspot.com

Comment: 2D or 3D ? there should be quick hacky ways to simplify the deflection angle computation (like 'un-rotate' the coordinate space so you can compute the deflection as if from a plane with no rotation using the rule of cosines). also I recommend having a peek at the bottlenecks using `jvisualvm`. care to post some code ?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a little, I found that, as should probably have been obvious to me, running that many functions seriously affects frameRate. I tried simplification  using Taylor Polynomials, but found that I couldn't really simplify my equations much without a great deal of error. The solution I settled on was a 3-dimensional array in my setup loop that precalculates a range of values suitable for my purposes. Thanks to everyone who replied for the help, I hope I didn't waste too much of your time.